# Cannot Query Users' OneDrive For Business Files As The Global Administrator using Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Logged in and authenticated as the Global Admin in O365 Enterprise subscription, I can query all users using Microsoft Graph. I can also query individual users with the `User.Id`.

But when I try to query the OneDrive files (`DriveItem`) for any user then I get an empty response and resource not found error. Same error when I use `UserPrincipalName` instead of `Id`.

sample request:

```
/v1.0/users/427d0a15-69db-4ab1-b7ae-542776ef53ed/drive/items
```

What is the call pattern for a Global Admin to query the drives/drive items of all users in the tenant?

I provided Admin Consent to the application already for these permissions:

```
public static string[] Scopes = {
    "Files.ReadWrite.All",
    "Sites.Read.All",
    "Sites.ReadWrite.All",
    "Sites.FullControl.All",
    "User.ReadWrite.All",
    "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
    "Directory.AccessAsUser.All"
};
```

I am using Delegated Permissions and requesting permissions at runtime via the code using `PublicClientApplication` class if that matters.

Update:
I get the same "Resource Not Found" error when I call:

```
/v1.0/users/427d0a15-69db-4ab1-b7ae-542776ef53ed/drive/root/children
```

Source code:

```
IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage usersCollection =
   await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();

foreach (User user in usersCollection)
{
   IDriveItemChildrenCollectionPage childrenCollection =
    await graphClient.Users[user.Id].Drive.Root.Children.Request().GetAsync();
}
```

When the Foreach loop iterates first time, the first user is the logged in Global Admin and the call to `Drive.Root.Children` works correctly, but on consequent iterations for other users, an exception is thrown with error message:

{"Code: itemNotFound\r\nMessage: The resource could not be found.\r\n\r\nInner error\r\n"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of trial and error I found out a workaround to the problem which I will post as an answer to help people having similar issues. If a better solution is provided I will accept that answer, so the hunt is still on..

It turns out that the Global O365 Admin does not by default have access to view OneDrive Business folders and files of other users in the tenant.

What I had to do is:

1. Login as the Global Admin to O365 portal
2. Go to Admin Center > Users
3. For each User, expand OneDrive Settings and click on "Access files"
   This gives permissions to manage that user's OneDrive.

After doing this:

```
/v1.0/users/427d0a15-69db-4ab1-b7ae-542776ef53ed/drive/root/children
```

returns properly all children of that users drive items!

I said I will accept a better answer, so to define better:

1. An answer that shows how to do this by code
2. Or an answer that at least shows how to do this with less clicks. Imagine if the tenant has 100K users, the global admin has to click that Access Files button for 100K users one by one! (no bulk settings option available) That s not a great experience and not a practical solution.

Best answer would be: 1 + 2 :)

UPDATE:
I found a better workaround, that is if I set the permissions in App Mod, as opposed to Delegated permissions/User Mod. Then the app has access to all users' drives/files in One Drive and there is no need for the global admin to provide himself the permissions as such. The enterprise admin would just need to give consent to the app only once in its lifetime in the enterprise tenant. With this update I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `[/drive/items][1]` directly. You need to either provide a `DriveItem.Id` (i.e. `/drive/items/{id}`) or a path (i.e. `/drive/root/children`).

Try this instead:

```
/v1.0/users/427d0a15-69db-4ab1-b7ae-542776ef53ed/drive/root/children
```

Comment: It did not work, I got the same resource not found error. Same error both when making the request from Graph Explorer page and also via the code/MS Graph Client. I copied the code snippet to the updated question and the point where I get the resource not found exception.

Comment: Is this user able to open their OneDrive via the web ui? This error implies there is a problem with their OD (i.e. it hasn't been provisioned yet).

Comment: All users can log in to portal and open their OneDrive by the web UI, upload files to it, share folders, use it in full functionality.

Comment: Just to confirm, the same user that fails to return `/drive/root/children` can see the files in the OneDrive for Business web app.

Comment: Every user including the one with the id above could use OneDrive with full functionality. If you are asking whether the global admin could see the files of the user via the web UI using ie. the url below:  
https://o365arslan-my.sharepoint.com/personal/testuser2_o365arslan_onmicrosoft_com  then answer is no. Global admin at that stage would get Access denied error. Only after my answer above then Global Admin could parse files of other users from web ui and ms graph calls with admin auth token started to retrieve files of other users.

Comment: This is what I was getting at, yes. Microsoft Graph cannot provide more "access" than a user (even an admin) would normally have. In the end it is acting on behalf of the user so it's constrained by the same policies.

Comment: Sure. But it is still not very clear to me that the Admin could basically grant the scopes/permissions to the app that he does not have at that stage. So a better and more consistent user experience would be that when the app requests these permissions, then the AAD call fails if the Admin did not yet have the File Access permissions at that point since these permissions were not given to him by default either.